# Some Can reach bidmail.com others can't

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-7, website, nslookup

On a Windows 7 Professional machine in Chrome one of our estimating assistants can't get to www.bidmail.com, however the other 3 can.  On his machine I did nslookup then bidmail.com and it fails to find it.  I then went to a machine that could reach bidmail and did nslookup. It can't find it.  I was skeptical and thought maybe it was a cached page so I cleared the cache then went back to bidmail.com was able to get to the page, login, lookup a newly posted bid then download the file.  Yet I can not look it up through nslookup and I can't ping it www.bidmail.com and I can't trace it.   I remoted to our other warehouse which is set up as a workgroup and attempt to nslookup bidmail and that nslookup fail... and on that machine which has never been to bidmail before it was able to connect to the website!

I am totally confused if I can't ping it and I can't use nslookup to get there how in the hell is Chrome getting to the page and how do I get this guy back on?

Also while typing this I took a new laptop out of the box plugged it in with no updates and can get to bidmail!

Comment: Please try using a browser other than Chrome so we can rule that out - I've had issue with Chrome caching/not flushing DNS in the past.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if bidmail.com is your site or not, but I'd start with testing the DNS of that domain. DNSCog has a number of errors coming up for bidmail.com: http://www.dnscog.com/report/bidmail.com

If it's your site, fix the error mentioned on that page and everyone will be able to access the site. If you are not, maybe try contacting the owners of the site. It appears to be a DNS configuration or DNS server problem.

Comment: Okay, looking closer at those DNS errors, it appears the site has some major issues. One out of their three DNS servers are responding, and when that one responds, it's responding with one of two different IPs. The only IP with seems to work for me is this one: 208.97.57.194. If you need your people to access this site urgently, try having them to go https://208.97.57.194

Comment: Answering with different IP's is normal, it's just a way of load-balancing (called Round-Robin-DNS sometimes).

Comment: @SvenW, very true, and thanks. I should have explained better: the DNS responds with one of two A records, browsing to one of them brings up the site, browsing to the other IP the connection times out. It might be the second IP is pointed to a server that only responds to hostnames, but in my mind, it would explain the issue this user is running into.

Comment: I only get 1 NS entry currently, and it only gives one answer, so I guess they are working on it on their side.